# Java: iText library PDF merging, pdf always on the bottom of the page

Tags: java, itext

I am using iText library for merging individual pdfs. But the individual pdf always come on the bottom of the page. Any pointer how I can make it to display in the middle or on teh top. I have adjusted my code from http://viralpatel.net/blogs/itext-tutorial-merge-split-pdf-files-using-itext-jar/
[image]

```
public static void concatPDFs(OutputStream outputStream, boolean paginate) {

        Document document = new Document();
        try {
            List<InputStream> pdfs = listPdf;
            List<PdfReader> readers = new ArrayList<PdfReader>();
            int totalPages = 0;
            Iterator<InputStream> iteratorPDFs = pdfs.iterator();

            // Create Readers for the pdfs.
            while (iteratorPDFs.hasNext()) {
                InputStream pdf = iteratorPDFs.next();
                PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdf);
                readers.add(pdfReader);
                totalPages += pdfReader.getNumberOfPages();
            }
            // Create a writer for the outputstream
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);

            document.open();
            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA,
                    BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent(); // Holds the PDF
            // data

            PdfImportedPage page;
            int currentPageNumber = 0;
            int pageOfCurrentReaderPDF = 0;
            Iterator<PdfReader> iteratorPDFReader = readers.iterator();

            // Loop through the PDF files and add to the output.
            while (iteratorPDFReader.hasNext()) {
                PdfReader pdfReader = iteratorPDFReader.next();

                // Create a new page in the target for each source page.
                while (pageOfCurrentReaderPDF < pdfReader.getNumberOfPages()) {
                    document.newPage();
                    pageOfCurrentReaderPDF++;
                    currentPageNumber++;
                    page = writer.getImportedPage(pdfReader,
                            pageOfCurrentReaderPDF);
                    cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);

                    // Code for pagination.
                    if (paginate) {
                        cb.beginText();
                        cb.setFontAndSize(bf, 9);
                        cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, ""
                                + currentPageNumber + " of " + totalPages, 520,
                                5, 0);
                        cb.endText();
                    }
                }
                pageOfCurrentReaderPDF = 0;
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            document.close();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (document.isOpen())
                document.close();
            try {
                if (outputStream != null)
                    outputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You had better use the samples provided by the iText people themselves, e.g. [Concatenate.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=123), if you really want to merge documents. (Those samples of course use current iText versions; the `PdfCopy` mechanism had already been there in ancient version, though.)

Comment: That example refers to `com.lowagie`, which is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

First to clear out about coordinate system. PDF coordinate system (0, 0) represents the bottom-left corner of the PDF page.

You can calculate new 'y' position for inserting page template like this:

y = new document heigh - imported page height

and then you can change your code to:

```
cb.addTemplate(page, 0, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do to merge PDF files is follow the intructions of the iText developer..

https://stackoverflow.com/a/24359217/2865036

Doing like he said, the format of your PDF files will not change