# Combining pdfs with itext - landscape pages rendered as portrait

Tags: java, itext

I'm maintaining a legacy application that uses itext to combine multiple landscape and portrait pdfs.  This process is working fine when combining pdfs produced by the same application, with other pdfs it renders landscape as portait and cuts off content.

Question:  Are there properties in the structure of the pdf that can cause such difference in rendering?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behavior you're describing only occurs if you follow bad examples. It doesn't occur when you follow [the official documentation](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf).

Although you didn't provide any source code, I'm pretty sure that you use a `PdfWriter` instance and that you add existing pages to the direct content of this instance using the `addTemplate()` method. This is (as I have pointed out many times to people who don't read the documentation) wrong.

You need to replace the merging process and use `PdfCopy` or `PdfSmartCopy` to concatenate PDF documents. Take a look at the [`MergeForms`](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/MergeForms) (merging forms) and [`FillFlattenMerge2`](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/reporting/FillFlattenMerge2) (introducing `PdfSmartCopy` so that the resulting file size remains low) examples for inspiration. If your application is really old, you may not find the `addDocument()` method.

In that case, you need to use old examples, such as the [`Concatenate`](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=123) example:

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));
document.open();
PdfReader reader;
int n;
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    reader = new PdfReader(files[i]);
    n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    for (int page = 0; page < n; ) {
        copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, ++page));
    }
    copy.freeReader(reader);
    reader.close();
}
document.close();
```